# How to assign values to each character and finds average using python or awk?

Tags: python, awk, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a text file which contains protein sequences(200 sequences) as shown below.

```
>ptn1
AAGHM
>ptn2
MGLKKRR
```

I need to give the following values to each character of the seqence and has to find the average of each sequence.

```
A= 0.2, G= 0.5, L=0.14, M= 0.70, R= 0.55, C=0.48, H= 1.00 , K=0.4
```

Desired output

```
ptn1  - 0.52
ptn2  - 0.462
```

How can I do this with awk or with python?

your suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: FYI biostar is a Q&A site for bioinformatics: http://www.biostars.org/show/questions/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Needs gawk for `FS=""`
http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Single-Character-Fields.html#Single-Character-Fields
Usage:
`awk -f foo.awk foo.txt`

```
BEGIN {
    FS=""
    k["A"]=0.2; k["G"]=0.5; k["L"]=0.14; k["M"]=0.70
    k["R"]=0.55; k["C"]=0.48; k["H"]=1.00; k["K"]=0.4
}

/^>/{
    $1=""
    name=$0
    next
}

{
    s=0
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      s+=k[$(i)]
    }
    printf "%s - %.3f\n", name, s/NF
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
def avg(sequence):
    v= {'A': 0.2, 'C': 0.48, 'R': 0.55, 'G': 0.5, 'H': 1.0,
        'K': 0.4, 'M': 0.7, 'L': 0.14}
    return sum(v[x] for x in sequence) / len(sequence)

avg("AAGHM")  # => 0.5199999999999999
avg("MGLKKRR" # => 0.46285714285714274
```

Comment: No need to call `list()`; strings are sequences too.

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence file appears to be in FASTA format. You should use a tool specifically suited for working with sequences, as opposed to custom parsing with tools like `awk`.

What if your file format changes? What if you want to extract meaningful data per the format specification? Already-built parsers are perfect for these questions.

I like [Biopython](http://biopython.org):

```
from Bio import SeqIO
records = SeqIO.parse("sequences.fasta", "fasta")

# Function borrowed from Tichodrama's answer
def avg(sequence):
    v= {'A': 0.2, 'C': 0.48, 'R': 0.55, 'G': 0.5, 'H': 1.0,
        'K': 0.4, 'M': 0.7, 'L': 0.14}
    return sum(v[x] for x in sequence) / len(sequence)

for record in records:
    print("Score for {}: {:.2f}".format(record.id, avg(record.seq)))
```

Note that each `record` above is a [`SeqRecord`](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqRecord) object that includes useful information, such as parsed defline information and the sequence alphabet (so you differentiate between protein sequences and DNA sequences, for example).

Answer (score 0):

```
mapping = {
    'A': 0.2,
    'G': 0.5,
    'L': 0.14,
    'M': 0.7,
    'R': 0.55,
    'C': 0.48,
    'H': 1.0,
    'K': 0.4}

def process(seqs):
    i = 0
    while i < len(seqs) - 1:
        print seqs[i].strip()[1:], '-', avg(seqs[i+1])
        i += 2

def avg(seq):
    return sum(mapping[v] for v in seq) / len(seq)

# assume the file is data.txt
process(open('data.txt').readlines())
```